# Concatenate /,: in a database row value after every 2 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table in SQL Server and inserted values in that table columns in time column I stored a long string value which I retrieved from a log.

That log returns a time string like this `'1103873704755'`, now I want to separate every 2 characters with `/`, (empty space) and K like this

```
'11/03/87 37:04:755'
```

Current query:

```
select top 1 Time 
from tbl_ModBus 
order by id desc
```

Output:

```
Time
-------------
1103873704755
```

Expected:

```
Time
-------------
11/03/87/ 37:04:755
```

So how can I get this string like I want using a SQL query?

Comment: don't store dates / times as strings

Comment: It looks like date/time but I have no idea what a final value of `755` would even mean...

Comment: it's Min.,Sec, and MillSec

Comment: `11/03/87 37:04:755` isn't a valid datetime

Comment: Your DBMS likely has some variant of the `subtring()` function (Sometimes also called `substr()`). Us it to get the parts of the string. Concatenate these parts and your separators to get the string you want. For concatenation, see some if a `concat()` (or maybe `concatenate()`) function or an operater (`||`, `+`) exists. But I also don't recommend to store timestamps as a string and think that value isn't a valid timestamp, at least if interpreted as you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is no a built in function to do this job in SQL.

It is always advised to use 'DATETIME ' when you are storing dates .

Yet, if you are storing data and time you better to use 'TIMESTAMP'.

Regarding all changes in the obtained value, you can do it in you programm code using whatever language you want !

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a string save as `DateTime`.becasue it will be Unstable

If you only want to do concrete `/,:` in a database row value after every 2 characters.

The easiest way, you can try to use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('1103873704755' AS BIGINT),'##/##/## ##:##:###')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/29163)

```
|                    |
|--------------------|
| 11/03/87 37:04:755 |
```